# How to use interp2 here

Tags: matlab, octave

I have this A matrix, 37x13, which has 4 "holes" poked into it, i've been asked to use interp2 to refill these values

```
    A=load ('archive');

    A(10,6)=0;
    A(10,7)=0;
    A(11,6)=0;
    A(11,7)=0;
```

I've used interp2 before this way but i'm afraid this does not work here, because the matrix has more than one row missing

```
    years = 1950:10:1990;
    service = 10:10:30;
    wage =   [150.697 199.592 187.625%10
      179.323 195.072 250.287
      203.212 179.092 322.767
      226.505 153.706 426.730
      249.633 120.281 598.243];
      %it is possible to interpolate to find the wage earned in 1975 by an employee 
      %with 15 years' service:

    w=interp2(service,years,wage,15,1975);
```

I need some guidance on how to declare the meshgrid command, the syntax of interp2 is what troubles me the most, interp1 was not really a trouble to learn in comparison.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `interp2` does not fill in "holes".  If these 0s are part of your original data, then the interpolated results at these locations will also be 0.  If you want to "fill in holes", you need to use something else other than `interp2`.  Perhaps what you can do is locate the locations that are 0 then fill in each of these holes with the average of the neighbourhood surrounding each 0.  That is done using things other than `interp2`.

Comment: I artificially made those "holes", the teacher told me those could be replaced with interp2, so then i could compare them to the original value, is that something that's not possible? even if instead of zero i use NaN?

Comment: It is possible if you replace the zeros with `NaN`.  Try John D'Errico's `inpaint_nan` function: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4551-inpaint-nans

Comment: I will begin testing on this and propose it as solution to my class.
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Comment: You can use [`griddata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) but as Rayryeng said, you can't use `interp2` here as it requires a complete grid and finds you values between grid points but it can't find you values that are missing on the grid. The only way to use `interp2` for this is to downsample your grid so the hole points no longer fit on the grid but this sacrifices precision unnecessarily. Each hole has 8 neighbouring points that you know, now instead of using all 8, you only use the 4 *corner* points. In that case you can use `interp2` but it's a poor choice.